# Gnuplot 5.0 dates on x-axis

Tags: gnuplot, axis

I'm trying to put dates on my x-axis. My data is plotted and correctly scaled but the x-axis only shows dates (correctly formatted) in a small range of August 1970. Here are the statements I'm using to set up the axis:

```
set format x "%Y%m%d" 
set xrange [ '19400101' : '20200101' ] noreverse nowriteback     
set xtics time
set xtics format "%m/%d/%Y"      
set xtics border out scale 3.5,1.5 nomirror rotate by 45  offset  character -5.5, -2.75
set xtics '19400101',  3.1536e+004,  '20200101' norangelimit  font "arial,10"
set xlabel "ASDF"       # <===== just a test--works fine
set xlabel  offset character 0, 0, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
```

If I type `show xrange` I get `[ 1.94001e+007 : 2.02001e+007 ]`. Shouldn't I 
be getting seconds from 01/01/1970?

What am I missing?

Al Chakrin

Answer (score 0):

there are several things:

1. first, one needs to make Gnuplot aware that the x-data is indeed time data with `set xdata time`
2. further, one should specify the input format of the time data. In this particular case, it would be `set timefmt "%Y%m%d"` (the commands `set format x` etc. only control how the date/time data is displayed not how it should be parsed)
3. in your plot, the tics spacing is specified as `3.1536e+004` (seconds). This will most likely result in `warning: Too many axis ticks requested`. If this number should represent one year, it should be set to `3.1536e+007 = 365*24*60*60` since the date/time data is internally indeed represented in terms of Unix timestamps (you can check this when you load your script by typing `print GPVAL_X_MAX` - this gives a value of `1577836800.0` which corresponds to the specified date of 1. 1. 2020)